# SQL Server 2008: What is lazy schema validation?

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

Saw this option when I made a linked server

Comment: is there another way to access data from a linked server other than open query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically it just enables you to improve performance for remote tables by not requesting meta data for each request, only when data is actually needed from the tables.

[Lazy Schema Validation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190918.aspx)

> If this option is set to false, the
> default value, SQL Server checks for
> schema changes that have occurred
> since compilation in remote tables.
> This check occurs before query
> execution. If there is a change in the
> schema, SQL Server recompiles the
> query with the new schema.
>
> If this option is set to true, schema
> checking of remote tables is delayed
> until execution. This can cause a
> distributed query to fail with an
> error if the schema of a remote table
> has changed between query compilation
> and execution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190918.aspx